# How to prove the following relation for rank of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

If $\mathbb{A}$ and $\mathbb{B}$ have same rows then how to show that the following relation holds $$\operatorname{rank}([\mathbb{A~B}])=\operatorname{rank}(\mathbb{A})+\dim(\text{Proj}_{\mathcal{A^C}}\mathcal{B})$$ where $\text{Proj}_{\mathcal{A^C}}\mathcal{B}$ is the projection of span of $\mathbb{B}$, denoted by $\mathcal{B}$, on the orthogonal complement of the span of $\mathbb{A}$, denoted by $\mathcal{A^c}$. $\dim$ denotes the number of dimension.

Comment: Deos $[\mathbb A \mathbb B]$ mean the matrix which contains column of $\mathbb A$ and then columns of $\mathbb B$? (Or is it product of the two matrices,) When you say "span of a matrix" do you mean the spaces generated by columns? (Or the space generated by rows?)

Comment: Did you mean to say that the two matrices have "the same *number* of rows" rather than just "the same rows"? (If you say that they have the same rows, it seems that $\mathbb A=\mathbb B$, or maybe they are not exactly the same but the order of rows might be changed.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you have the space $\mathcal A=[\vec a_1,\dots,\vec a_k]$ generated by the columns of $\mathbb A$ and $\mathcal B=[\vec b_1,\dots,\vec b_l]$ generated by the columns of $\mathbb B$. And you are asking about the dimension of
$$\mathcal A+\mathcal B=[\vec a_1,\dots,\vec a_k,b_1,\dots,\vec b_l].$$
You can write each vector $\vec b_i$ as
$$\vec b_i=\underset{\in\mathcal A}{\underbrace{\vec b'_i}}+\underset{\in\operatorname{Proj}_{\mathcal A^c}\mathcal B}{\underbrace{\vec b''_i}}.$$ 
From this you get
$$\mathcal A+\mathcal B=[\vec a_1,\dots,\vec a_k,b''_1,\dots,\vec b''_l]=\mathcal A \oplus \operatorname{Proj}_{\mathcal A^c}\mathcal B$$
and this implies the claim about dimensions.